# Two questions about XSLT

Tags: xslt

I have now two questions about xslt.

First, I want to describe all of elements which without any attribute. Like

```
<element id="p0" attribute="a1"/>
<element id="p1"/>
<element id="p2"/>
```

I need a group of elements without attribute="a1", so just need p1 and p2. With XSLT, should I write `<xsl:if test="element[@attribute]=''">`? Because when I test it, I found it doesn't work. So please help me.

The second is, I want to make the output result not in the same line. Like

right:

```
t11

t22

t33
```

wrong:

```
t11t22t33
```

which XSLT word should I write? Thanks a bunch.

Comment: You want to get all the values of the attribute name `attribute`? And all these values should get outputted on a newline?

Comment: No. I want to select all of the elements without any attributes. And the output result, I just don't want that they stand in one line.

Comment: Where are the values `t11`, `t22` and `t33` coming from? Maybe best to provide a complete input XML

Comment: hey mark, "t11 t22 t33" is just make an example.They are the output value. So I want to ask which xslt word or sentence is useful for that they stand in different lines? Thank u so much.

Answer (score 0):

1. All relative paths in an `xsl:template` are evaluated against the node that was matched by the template. So `<xsl:if test="element[@attribute]=''">` is testing for the presence of a child of the current node called `element` that matches your condition. If this test is located in a template that matches `element` nodes, then it's not going to work. You should use `.` to refer to the current node.
2. The boolean expression `element[@attribute]=''` is looking for an `element` node that has an attribute called `attribute` and that is itself empty. It doesn't test anything about the content of the `attribute` attribute.

Basically, you need to understand the following template:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:template match="element">
        <xsl:text>element position=[</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="count(preceding-sibling::element) + 1"/>
        <xsl:text>] / </xsl:text>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test=".[not(@attribute)]">
                <xsl:text>no @attribute</xsl:text>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test=".[@attribute='']">
                <xsl:text>empty @attribute</xsl:text>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:text>non-empty @attribute</xsl:text>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
        <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to this test document:

```
<root>
    <element id="p0" attribute="a1">one</element>
    <element id="p1" attribute="test"></element>
    <element id="p1" attribute=""></element>
    <element id="p2">three</element>
</root>

element position=[1] / non-empty @attribute
element position=[2] / non-empty @attribute
element position=[3] / empty @attribute
element position=[4] / no @attribute
```

This template also answers your second question about newlines.

Answer (score 0):

With this stylesheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

    <xsl:output indent="no" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each select="root/element[not(@attribute='a1')]">
            <xsl:value-of select="@id"/><xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

when applied to this input:

```
<root>
    <element id="p0" attribute="a1"/>
    <element id="p1"/>
    <element id="p2"/>
</root>
```

outputs:

```
p1
p2
```